# Does Duff's Device Speed up Java Code?

Tags: java, duffs-device

Using the stock Sun 1.6 compiler and JRE/JIT, is it a good idea to use the sort of extensive unroll exemplified by Duff's Device to unroll a loop? Or does it end up as code obfuscation with no performance benefit?

The Java profiling tools I've used are less informative about line-by-line CPU usage than, say, valgrind, so I was looking to augment measurement with other people's experience.

Note that, of course, you can't *exactly* code Duff's Device, but you can do the basic unroll, and that's what I'm wondering about.

```
        short stateType = data.getShort(ptr);
        switch (stateType) {

        case SEARCH_TYPE_DISPATCH + 16:
            if (c > data.getChar(ptr + (3 << 16) - 4)) {
                ptr += 3 << 16;
            }
        case SEARCH_TYPE_DISPATCH + 15:
            if (c > data.getChar(ptr + (3 << 15) - 4)) {
                ptr += 3 << 15;
            }
         ...
```

down through many other values.

Comment: I don't understand your revised question.  Duff's device does not mean just fall-through.  The interlaced loop is a key part.

Comment: Why don't you ... test it?

Write a version with the loop as usual.  Write a version with the unrolled loop.  Write a framework that executes each on a million times (or whatever).  See what, if any, performance gains come from your optimization attempt.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't much matter whether it's a good idea (it's not), because it won't compile.

EDIT: This is mentioned explicitly [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> A trick known as Duff's device can be used in C or C++ to unroll the loop, but this is not valid code in the Java programming language:

Or, more bluntly (from the same section):

> Great C hack, Tom, but it's not valid here.

EDIT: To answer your more (too) general question, usually no.  You should generally rely on the JIT.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the question quite unspecific enough.

Comment: I know it's 10 years later. But are we call clear that 'Tom' is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Duff

Answer (score 8):

You are ignoring the fact that Java compiles to bytecodes for a stack-oriented virtual machine. Whatever low-level optimization trick you attempt at the Java level is largely ineffective. The real optimization happens when the JIT compiler produces the assembly for the target architecture, a process that you can neither control nor care about for the most part.

You should instead optimize at a much larger picture. Let the JIT compiler handle the low-level optimizations.

Comment: I'm not ignoring it, I'm asking you about it.